# How to remove TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

```py
cursor = collection.find({{"colourCode" : "orange" },{"createdOn":{ "$gt" : my_datetime}},{"assignmentRef":{'$ne':None}}},{'createdOn':1,'assignmentRef.name':1,'_id':0,'colourCode':1})

list_cur = list(cursor)

df = DataFrame(list_cur)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Your `collection.find()` method syntax is not correct - the filter has braces (`{` and `}`) incorrectly formatted. Refer the documentation for correct usage.

Comment: @prasad_ what is the correct format then? could you give correct syntax for the above code?

Comment: @prasad_ please rewrite the code with correct syntax so that I clearly can understand it.